# Why was this reopened?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42154/how-do-i-make-my-browser-extension-known-to-the-chess-community) was closed for being off-topic and better suited for community building by me, a bunch of other users, and a moderator (I think Brian Towers) yesterday. Then Federico Potoni removed some advertising, which was even what it was closed for (but still a good edit). For some reason they also pressed the sumbit for review, when the close reason was clearly not resolved. Then Rewan Demontay and a second moderator (I believe Glorfindel) reopened it. Why was it reopened?

Answer (score 1):

Because three people (the editor too, see the [edit summary](https://chess.stackexchange.com/revisions/42154/3)) felt it deserved another chance? We're not Stack Overflow which gets flooded with bad questions, we can afford to give questions a little more care. I don't know the answer to the question, but I can imagine there's a chess-oriented marketplace / community for software like this (one of the comments gives some pointers).

If other users think it's still too much of a [recommendation question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173762/295232), they can still close it again; my vote is not binding in that sense. But other recommendation questions (e.g. for books) usually stay open on this site, also because we can support them better than larger sites.

By the way, the list of close and reopen voters is public; it's visible in the question's [timeline](https://chess.stackexchange.com/posts/42154/timeline).

Comment: It was closed for being off-topic not because it is related to a recommendation.

Comment: *Other, less specifically chess-related subjects may also be on-topic, depending on how chess-related the specific Q&A is. These gray-area questions include topics of etiquette, psychology, software, books/articles/media, as well as other subjects. Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.*

Comment: This was only about publicizing something to the chess community, and as such I suggested it was better for community building. A bunch of other people agreed with me and closed it as off topic. Then an edit was made that didnt make it more on topic, and yet it was reopened?? @Glorfindel

Comment: It's definitely not suitable for [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm glad it didn't get migrated there.

Comment: It about "building a community to use my product" aka "Community building" @Glorfindel

Comment: No, he wants to publish something, not build a community around his product. (BTW, you don't need to @ me, comments under a post always ping the post author. And you as well, as long as we're the only people in this comment thread.)

Comment: "How do I make my browser extension known to the chess community?" is about "making it known" and "getting a community" and "advertising". From your link: "Creating, expanding, and cultivating communities, their content, and the relationships among members. This includes things like attracting new people with advertising, getting more contributions from members, moderating your moderators, or just making your community grow as a whole." That is what that question is.

Comment: No, it's not. Just pretend the question used the words "all people who play chess".

Comment: Still about advertising and getting a community, rewording to say the same thing doesnt change the meaning